# Align text in the center of a RectangleShape

Tags: c++, sfml, text-alignment

I am currently trying to write a button class in SFML/C++, however I'm having trouble aligning the text in the middle of the button.

I've been using the standard alignment formula (button x position / 2) - (text width / 2) and (button y position / 2) - (text height / 2)

```
void setPosition(sf::Vector2f point) {
        button.setPosition(point);
        float xPos = (point.x / 2) - (text.getLocalBounds().width / 2);
        float yPos = (point.y / 2) - (text.getLocalBounds().height / 2);
        text.setPosition(xPos, yPos);
    }
```

The result of this code is that the text shoots up and to the left, and is definitively not in the center. I'm sure it has something to do with how SFML set up their coordinates almost inversely, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This formula seemed to work out for me:

```
void setPosition(sf::Vector2f point) {
        button.setPosition(point);
        float xPos = (point.x + btnWidth / 2) - (text.getLocalBounds().width / 2);
        float yPos = (point.y + btnHeight / 2) - (text.getLocalBounds().height / 2);
        text.setPosition(xPos, yPos);
    }
```